# Что придет на смену Java?

Tags: java

Java 7 - "прыжок в пропасть"? Что (и кто) придет на смену Java?

Comment: Питон (только с фигурными скобочками).

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду Groovy? ;)
На самом деле Scala - вполне достойная альтернатива в рамках JRE для тех, кто прочит смерть Java.

Comment: Ну займут они все вместе процентов 20 от рынка, на этом все и закончится) Java еще .Net переживет. щас в ней порядок тока наведут. Да Кложур забыли, куда же без лиспа теперь)))))

Comment: Java 7 - "прыжок в пропасть" - с чего вы взяли? обоснуйте

Comment: Обратите внимание, что автор задал провокационный вопрос с броским заголовком, и сам слился и не участвует в дискуссии. Думаю, вопрос стоит закрыть как близкий к троллингу.

Answer (score 1):

Задающих такие вопросы приглашаем вслед за ней :) Ну, а если серьёзно, то если вдруг Java загнётся через пяток лет, то альтернатив вообще никаких, только .NET.

**UPD** похоже, мой ответ был не совсем верно понят. Сам я лично не думаю, что это прыжок в пропасть. Думаю, всё пока неплохо выглядит.

**UPD** остальные варианты, такие как питон, скала и ещё что-то не рассматриваются как альтернатива, так как они мало приспособлены для серьёзной Enterprise-разработки. Тот же питон просто не годится для таких вещей. А пригодная альтернатива имеется только одна.

Comment: А отчего она может загнуться? Из-за лицензионных ограничений? Мне кажется, с таким количеством существующего кода (+ развивающиеся напрвления, например, Андроид), 5 лет - это разве что если все компьютеры сгорят из-за конца света в 2012.

Comment: Ну, при неправильном подхоже оракл запросто может это реализовать.

Comment: Выживаемость языков программирования в значительной степени обусловлена объёмом накопленного кода. Джаве по этой причине (много написано, много людей умеют писать) в ближайшие годы серьёзно ничего не грозит.

Comment: Посмотрите вакансии, их куча и они хорошо оплачиваются, как то не пахнет смертью. В Oracle никогда дураки не работали, у них наоборот глобальные идеи по завоеванию. Постоянно проходят конференции по теме объединения многих стандартов с .NET. Собираются вводить модульность в JDK чтобы такая же фича с различными языками была как в .Net с его ядром CLR. Многие стандарты хотят сделать едиными для .NET и Java. Читайте больше новостей. Oracle просто хочет избавится от непрофильных и убыточных активов, MySQL им вообще как то не к месту.

Comment: Если Java и загнется, то не скоро. А загнется она под собственным весом. Слишком много всего наработано, концов не найдешь. Куча времени уходит на поиск решений, освоение очередных концепций, расширяющих чего-нибудь. Со временем желающих освоить это богатство будет все меньше и меньше, развитие остановится. 

Кстати, знатоки Java, помогите пожалуйста найти ответ на недавно заданный здесь вопрос: 

Как создать файл ? (java gwt eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Позвольте высказаться: какой прыжок в пропасть, Вы о чем вообще говорите?

1. У Оракла куча Java-ориентированных продуктов, которые стоят кучу денюшек, кроме того чаще всего сама СУБД Оракл применяется совместно с Java-решениями (целый стек технологий).
2. Миллионы строк Java-кода (сайты, мобильные приложения, GUI, либы, веб-сервера), которые нужно поддерживать.
3. Java 7 внесет часть интересных плюшек в язык: проверка на null, более удобные исключения (как же мне этого не хватает), строки в switch, проект Coin. Линк вам - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082555/best-java-7-features
4. Большие крупные стартапы, сайты так или иначе в большинстве своем используют JVM (Scala, Java), например, "Одноклассники" в России.
5. Отец Java, Джеймс Гослинг, работает сейчас в VW, и что вы думаете там применяется? Естественно Java, таким образом появляются новые области применения.
6. Да хотя бы посмотрите на статистику меток на данном ресурсе :) Java на втором месте по их количеству.

Comment: что за VW? фольцваген чтоли? Он уж несколько месяцев в Goole работает.

Comment: Да подзабыл я историю эту уже, сейчас так, но с фолксвагеном он сотрудничал, и эти слова были из интервью в России. Год не скажу.

Comment: Интересный факт, не знал....